# React webcam library stop button not working with iphone in react js

Tags: reactjs

Stop recording video is not works with iphone, But its works with androind mobile

```
const handleStopCaptureClick = useCallback(() => {
    mediaRecorderRef.current.stop();
    setCapturing(false);
  }, [mediaRecorderRef, setCapturing]);
```